# Webview on react-native android doesn't load embed youtube url

Tags: android, reactjs, android-webview, react-native, react-native-scrollview

```
import React, { View, WebView }  from 'react-native';

export const YoutubeScreen = React.createClass({
 render: function() {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}> 
      <WebView
      style={{flex:1}}
      javaScriptEnabled={true}
      source={{uri: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZZ5LpwO-An4?rel=0&autoplay=0&showinfo=0&controls=0'}}
    />
   </View>
 );
} 
});
```

On iOS works fine. Is that a bug or a normal behaviour for android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue.

[Webview on android doesn't load embed youtube url #6405](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6405)